# Modifying final fields inside the class in Dart

Tags: variables, dart, final

Dart docs read:

> If you never intend to change a variable, use final or const, either
>   instead of var or in addition to a type. A final variable can be set
>   only once;

Ok, this means that assigning a final variable second time will not work, **but** nothing
is said about modifying, i.e.

```dart
void main() {
  final List<int> list = [1,2,3];  

  list = [10, 9, 8]; //error!

  list
  ..clear()
  ..addAll([10, 9, 8]); //works!
}
```

As one can see, in essence, I *re-* assigned final variable `list`. Doesn't it contradict the whole idea of final variables?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`final` doesn't mean **deep** `final`.

The `list` variable references still the same list instance even when you modify the lists content. Any mutable instance can be modified even when it was assigned to a final variable.
Imagine

```dart
void main() {
  var l = [1,2,3];
  final List<int> list = l;  
}
```

Now you wouldn't be able to modify the items in the list referenced by `l` because the list is also assigned to the final field `list` (both `list` and `l` reference the same list). That doesn't make sense.

What you can do to make the list immutable is

```dart
final List<int> list = const[1,2,3];
```

Now you can't assign another list to `list` and you can't modify the contents of the list referenced by `list`.

An alternative way

```dart
  import 'dart:collection'
  ...
  var l = [1,2,3];
  final List<int> list = UnmodifiablyListView(l);
```

Now you can't modify `list` or the contents of the list referenced by `list` but you can modify the contents referenced by `l` (`list` would reflect the changes made to `l`).
If you loose the reference to `l` you have no way of modifying the contents.

```dart
  var l = [1,2,3];
  final List<int> list = UnmodifiablyListView(l);
  l = null;
```

`final` is nice when you for example want to ensure that the `list` field never is set to `null`.

```dart
class MyModel {
  final list = [];
}
```

The `list` field is public but nobody can set `list` to for example `null`.

```dart
var model = new MyModel();
...
model.list.forEach(print);
```

will never fail with an exception like `null doesn't have a method 'forEach'`.
This is similar but more concise than

```dart
class MyModel {
  var _list = [];
  List get list => _list;
}
```

Comment: However, if one codes `void main() { final List<int> list = [1,2,3]; List<int> l=list; l=[10,9,8]; }` then at `l=[10,9,8]` a deep copy of `list` will be created; One can see that clearly in the debugger: at line 2 id's of `l` and `list` will be the same, i.e. they refer to the same object in memory, while at line 3, these references will be different. I agree, your first example does not make any sense, but the bahaviour I described does not seem to be very meaningful either, i.e. why at all have finals if there is such a simple way to re-assign them? Prev comment didn't come out right.

Comment: I don't know why you think a deep copy is created. With `l = [10,9,8];` you created a new (2nd) list with different values. `list` still refers the first list and `l` refers a completely different list.

Comment: yes, i misinterpreted the case. thanks for explanations.

Answer (score 4):

This is a `const` vs `final` confusion. Here's the difference:

`final` - means you can't use the operator `=`. But you can add, or remove items. The assignment is final, however, the values are NOT constant.

Example:

```
void main() {
  final List<int> list = [1,2,3];  

  print(list); // [1, 2, 3]
  list.add(5); // Works!
  print(list); // [1, 2, 3, 5]
}
```

`const` - means you can't re-assign nor change the values.

```
void main() {
  const List<int> list = [1,2,3];  

  print(list); // [1, 2, 3]
  list.add(5); // Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: add
  print(list);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition to Adrian's answer, I am just starting out with Dart and I had a little bit of trouble understanding it until I broke it down for myself.
The final keyword cannot be changed when it has been assigned to a variable(use this preferably at run-time) to initialize.[they are often instance variables]
The const keyword is preferably used for class variables(static const) and declaring constant variables. they cannot be changed at all until run-time initialization.
But when we get to lists, the explanations for final and const become more narrow.
final lists cannot be changed only modified using .add() or .remove(), meaning the assignment is final but the values are not
const lists and cannot be mutated in any way, they are final and that closes the use of the initialized list.
I hope this helps.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#variables