# Why final variable allowed to change its value?

Tags: dart

```dart
void main() {
  final num = [];
  num.add(1);
  print(num);  
}
```

Output

```
1
```

If a `final` variable is initialized it can't be changed but why does it allow me to change the value whereas it doesn't allow me to reassign the value like `num = 5;`?

Comment: ["final" means single-assignment: a final variable or field must have an initializer. Once assigned a value, a final variable's value cannot be changed. final modifies variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50431087/7666442)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying final fields inside the class in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235849/modifying-final-fields-inside-the-class-in-dart)

Comment: Because that var is final and you cannot change it to DIFFERENT array - but array itself is mutable and you are allowed to change its internal state (eg adding elements)

Answer (score 5):

By calling

`final nums = [];`

you created an empty List of dynamic types.

[image]

This list by itself is final and you can't reassign it

[image]

However, you can easily add new items to the List as this is just a method on the List.

In other words making a variable `final` means that it cannot be reassigned, but it doesn't mean that it cannot change.

> A final variable can be set only once

Please refer to the [Dart language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const) to learn more.

One important remark is that [num](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.0/dart-core/num-class.html) is a class in Dart that may be double or integer, so it's not a good practice to use it as variable name.