# How is it possible to add or remove method to final list?

Tags: flutter, list, dart, final

I have fount out something. Assume, we have a final list and when I wanna use add or remove method, it allows to use. For example:

```
void main() {

  final exaList=[1,2,3,4];
  exaList.add(100);
  
  print(exaList);
}
```

I can't understand. I have added the final tag but that list still use add or remove methods. Please can anyone explain this situation?

Many Thanks..

Comment: Check this comment

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26236006/12083662

Comment: final is you cant re assign this variable into new or different list, const mean you can't change its value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See that's the difference between a final variable and a const variable. You cannot change the value of a final variable but you can modify it however you want which means that add or remove functions will work on the `final` variable, but if you want a completely immutable variable then what you need is `const`:

```
void main() {
  
 const exaList=[1,2,3,4];
  exaList.add(100);
  
  print(exaList);
}
```

If you want, you can try to run this to understand how a `final` variable works :

```
void main() {
  
  final exaList=[1,2,3,4];
  exaList = [2,3,4,5];
  
  print(exaList);
}
```